# Cross-browser, synchronous, dynamic loading of script

Tags: javascript

I need a way to dynamically load a JS file synchronously.

My thought was to make an XHR request for the script (which in this case is CDN dojo) but I run into the cross domain origin policy issue. Any suggestions would be huge. Thanks!

Comment: Does this have to be done dynamically?  Scripts tend to be fairly small files.  Couldn't you either load them all, or pick them during page rendering (via PHP, or whatever server-side you're using)?  I mean, I can think of situations in which you wouldn't want to do that, but they're all pretty far-fetched.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you try another approach rather than having them load synchronously. Most, if not all, script loaders load scripts asynchronously due to the nature of how they load them (dynamic script tags).

I suggest you take a look at module loaders like [RequreJS](http://requirejs.org/)